How to call AWS Bedrock asynchronously
Is there a way to call Bedrock claude3 model with Python SDK asynchronously?
More specifically, I want the results to be sent to S3.

Batch inference is asynchronous, but it's in preview.

tnx! do you know if there is a similar feature in Langchain?

LangChain provides document loader (from S3 dir or file) and LLM (Bedrock) but I'm unaware of any file writer.
